# Should I use auto layout in Xcode 6 or should I prefer using separate storyboards for all iOS devices

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode6

I am having real difficult time using auto layout as when I sometimes change the views, it becomes a real mess with the already assigned constraints. So should I really give more time to myself learning auto layout or should I just go with multiple storyboards as it takes a bit of time but ultimately makes it easier for us to change the design easily in future.

Comment: Yes, at the beginning you'll have lots of difficulties. I was going mad at the beginning. Try, try, try. One good tip about constraints: always use minimum-necessary number of constraints. And till now I always managed to use only universal (Any-Any) size class for all the devices. In the end - auto layout is amazing peace of help for GUI.

Answer (score 2):

From my learning,

I felt the same because its hard to learn and understand `AutoLayout` for first time. Here is the lot of advantages using

**AutoLayout Advantages**

Future iOS Versions going to support auto layout

It will save you lot of your time when ever new version of OS get released

**Using Multiple StoryBoard**

You need to maintain for each screen which is clearly hassle if you want to change anything in your View.

It will eat lot of your time to fixing 
 and much more

Spend little time in `AutoLayout`. Its not that hard to learn.

[Auto Layout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk)

[Size Class Explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng)

I am sure above link will help for all beginners.

Answer (score 1):

In new Xcode you can find Size Classes in Storyboard which helps to manage various screen sizes. On beginning it seems to be hard but after little time it will save you lots of work.

I suggest to start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/_index.html

It is important to create proper constraint. Set on view size class: Any x Any and then you can create constraints automatically, clicking Editor -> Resolve Autolayout Issues -> Reset To suggested Constraints or use shortcut: **Command** + **Option** + **Shift** + "**=**" while object in storyboard is selected. Honestly, it doesn't work properly in each case, sometimes you just have to set it manually.

Summarizing it's worth lo learn AutoLayout and make all screen sizes in one Storyboard.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. Thanks for the link. It helped me solve my problem too.

Answer (score 1):

The practice we are using is always splitting the Storyboards into smaller chunks, because they get ridiculously big and hard to work on. But we are not splitting them for different devices, but feature-wise. For example the Onboarding process has a separate Storyboard.

*But we are always using auto-layout and iOS 8 size classes to support different devices. In some cases we even code constraints in code.*

**So learn Auto-layout sooner rather than later, it will save you time on multiple occasions.**